# Trigger Functionality on Show

Tags: jquery, jplayer

i've been trying to use the observer pattern on the following functionality,

I have the following code

`$('.popup-vimeo').magnificPopup({
      type: 'iframe',
    callbacks: {
       open: function() {`

```
                  // $(".jPlayer").trigger( $.jPlayer.event.pause );
                  $('body').trigger('supperPause');



                },
                close: function() {
                  // Will fire when popup is closed


                  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");


                }
                // e.t.c.
          }
        })`
```

And here is the observer

`$('body').on('supperPause', function() {
                console.log( 'yeah supperpause');
                $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('pause');
            });`

What this is not doing is pause / playing the jPlayer functionality. Hope this helps and here is the site in case you need it [Player Site](http://tylerbates.innovacionesweb.info)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution i was referencing the wrong element, here is a solution in case someone needs it `myPlaylist.play();`

If using playlists you need to reference it like so.

Hope this helps some one.